# Loop in VBA to add extension .jpg

Tags: excel, vba, loops, concatenation

I am really new to VBA and I would like to add a .jpg extension to values contained in a column.

```
Header Col G
11125;111545
154645
154511;145521;165421
1156556;13165
567418
```

I would like to loop into this column and add a .jpg to every value (multiple images per cell tho')

EDIT: 2n Try and working one

```
Sub image()
Dim c As Range


    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        Dim Words() As String
        Words() = Split(c.Value, ";")
        Dim x As Integer

        For x = 0 To UBound(Words)
        Words(x) = Words(x) & ".jpg"
        Next x
        c.Value = Join(Words, ";")
    Next
End Sub
```

Probably not the shortest way..but it works 
Thank you

Comment: if your solution is working, you should post it as an answer not an edit so you can help someone more easily in the future

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a non-standard way to do it...

Select your cells

```
dim c as range
for each c in Selection.cells
    c.value = Join(Split(c.value,";"),".jpg;") & ".jpg"
    'This is what I'd actually use:
    'c.value = Replace(c.value, ";", ".jpg;") & ".jpg"
next
```

To answer your edited question, what you are doing wrong is:

```
c.Value = Words(x) & ".jpg"
```

Here you are overwriting the value of c.Value through each iteration and adding ".jpg", so it will only have the last value in the end.

If you want to keep using your method I'd suggest something like:

```
dim temp
temp = ""
for x = Lbound(Words) to Ubound(Words)
   temp = temp & Words(x) & ".jpg"
next x
c.value = temp
```

Comment: Won't work because the last value of each cell doesnt end by ";". If it did...a simple search/replace would do the trick

Comment: I edited the question with a code try... but I can get multiple values cell work

Comment: I've found a way longer but working way. See OP. Your method is quick & clean. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub image()
Dim c As Range


    For Each c In Selection.Cells
        Dim Words() As String
        Words() = Split(c.Value, ";")
        Dim x As Integer

        For x = 0 To UBound(Words)
        Words(x) = Words(x) & ".jpg"
        Next x
        c.Value = Join(Words, ";")
    Next
End Sub
```